Since when did iproute2 support source-based routing?
I've searched about source-based routing and all resources say I must use policy-based routing with ip rule. But I have tried the following and it actually works
$ ip -6 route
default via fe80::1 dev eth0 proto static metric 1024 pref medium
default from 2001:1111::/64 dev eth1 proto static metric 1024 pref medium

Traffic from 2001:1111::/64 actually got routed via eth1 instead of eth0.
How is this possible? iproute2 manpages does not mention the from syntax when ip route add routes. What's going on?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@ilkkachu that section was under "ip route show", not under "ip route add", which is even more confusing.

@user17239, oh dear, indeed. That's what I get for trying to read a long document on the phone. Hmmh.
